# Require_Once gives PHP Division By Zero Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to require a config file in index.php by using:

```
require_once __DIR__/application/common/config/Config.php;
```

However, PHP error logs state division by zero.  The full path is /var/www/application/common/config/Config.php

How do I ensure this path is correctl represented in my require_once statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes for strings in PHP...

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/application/common/config/Config.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of a series of design mistakes in PHP.

- PHP converts every symbol it does not know to a string, except it has a leading upper character, that will be a constant.
- Constants that are not defined are `NULL`
- When you try any mathematical operation on a string, it gets converted to an integer.

  - `"123"` will be 123
  - `"123 abc"` will be 123 as well
  - `"abc"` will be 0.
- When you try any mathematical operation on `NULL`, it gets converted to `0`

So what happens, is that PHP calculates `"yourdirectory"/0/0/0/0`, which is a division by zero. (*Ouch!* [Did I already tell you that PHP is a broken language?](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/))

Just put the string in quotes.

```
require_once __DIR__."/application/common/config/Config.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/application/common/config/Config.php';
```

that should work? The "." concatenates the string. Basically " **dir** " (plus) 'other values'. and the other values need to be in quotes, otherwise it will take "/" as a basic math operator, thus trying to divide everything by 0 in the rest of the statement.

(require_once **DIR**/0/0/0/0;) and you can't divide by 0 ;)